# Rails deployment with custom directory on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Let's assume I have git repository `repo` and rails application in `repo/rails`. By default Heroku uploads the whole repository which I do not want. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: why you have a subfolder ar all?

Comment: why not? (of course there is more to version than just the rails app)

Comment: E.g. Scripts that are related to data but not the rails app

Comment: just use the script folder in your rails.root :>

Comment: So I need to break my directory structure? That's stupid. And how do I avoid that it doesn't get uploaded to heroku?

Comment: I don't understand why people act against rails conventions...

Comment: This has little to do with rails per se, more with git and heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Do it the standard Heroku way.
Long answer: you may be able to hack something together with a [custom](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) Heroku [ruby buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby), but it probably wouldn't be fun.